# Is there any alternate to BoxedApp SDK?

Tags: file, virtual

BoxedApp http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/ is useful to write programs which need virtual or fake file.
I want to know is there any other Library or Component as an alternative to this for free?
The reason that I need such thing is, I have a stream in memory and need it to play. (stream is  a film)
any free alternative? (BoxedApp can handle it.)

Comment: Alternative to BoxedApp : Cameyo, Dokany, Eldos Solid File System.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Microsoft Detours can be alternative to BoxedApp. As for another alternatives - I do not know. 
Good luck